# scanf not running multiple times in loops C

Tags: c, eclipse, singly-linked-list

so this is my code for creating and  printing a linked list. I wrote this code in atom ide but when i run the code there is a problem with asking input as shown in output below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node * createl(int n);

void printlist(struct node* head2);

int main() {
    struct node *mainhead;
    int n;

    printf("Enter the number of nodes : " );
    scanf("%d",&n );
    mainhead=createl(n);
    printlist(mainhead);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void printlist(struct node * head2)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=head2;
    printf("\nLinked List : \n" );
    while (ptr!=NULL) {
        printf("%d => ",ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

}


struct node * createl(int n)
{
    struct node *head=NULL,*iso=NULL,*p=NULL;
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
        setbuf(stdout,NULL);
        iso=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nEnter data in node no. %d :",i+1);
 
        scanf("%d",&(iso->data));
        iso->next=NULL;

        if (head=NULL)
        {
            head=iso;
        } else {
            p=head;
            while (p->next!=NULL) {
                p=p->next;
            }
            p->next=iso;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return head;
}
```

The expected Output should be:

```
Enter number of node : 5
Enter data in node no 1 : 1
Enter data in node no 2 : 2
Enter data in node no 3 : 3
Enter data in node no 4 : 4
Enter data in node no 5 : 5
```

Linked List :
1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => 5

But the actual output it shows is :

```
Enter the number of nodes : 4
Enter data in node no. 1 : 1
program ends
```

Comment: Post the actual input and output as text, not image please

Comment: You do not check the return value from `scanf` so how do you know the input succeeded?

Comment: @kartik30369 Save time and enable all warnings.  A good compiler would warn about `if (head=NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is *setting* `head` to `NULL` when it should be *evaluating* it for `NULL`:

Change this

```
if (head=NULL)//assignment, leaves head NULL when executed
```

to

```
if (head==NULL)//evaluates head, but does not change it.
```

3 additional suggestions:

- When memory created using `malloc()` is no longer needed, it should be freed.

  `....`
  `getch();`
  `//free Each node that was created`
- [Casting the return of `malloc()` in C is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

  `//iso=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
  `iso=malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
- `getch()` is `POSIX` only, and is not portable.  A portable alternative is [getchar()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `createl` function, in the `if` case. You need to change from
`if (head = NULL)` to `if (head == NULL)` and it will work.

Another 2 things:

1. In the function `printlist`, your last element will print `x =>` and not `x`.
2. You need to free your `struct node* mainhead` at the end of the main.

Comment: And also free all the nodes that `mainhead` points to.